# COM Port not available on Mongoose OS for IoT sensor device TI CC3200

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot, google-cloud-iot, mongoose-os

Just want to build Google IOT core with mongoose OS running for sensing temperature data on google PUBSUB.

I have a problem starting from beginning while not able to the connect via an approved google Core IOT Device - "TI CC3200". Its not able to connect to Mongoose OS. Its getting "access denied" on all COM ports, tried almost all changing COM 1,2,34,5…not working at all…10 times restarted system. Already Installed all required COM Drivers required for Windows 10. Just want to connect Mongoose OS and Sensortag CC3200 and later integrate with GCP Core IOT to push data further.

I am referring this blog post provided by Mongoose OS Team for integration.
https://mongoose-os.com/docs/mongoose-os/cloud/google.md

[MOS Screen here for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cj5O.png)

I have tried on other windows 10 and Windows 8 PC, but no success. Same error Access Denied on Mongoose OS screen

Access denied on MOS Screen immediately

Comment: Thanks! Please try on OSX, see if it works...For me I am out of all options, TI CC3200 should work with Mongoose OS as per guideline both from Google and Mongoose OS, definitely you are right, in terms of drivers are out dated. How to get correct ones working

Comment: I am using SimpleLink Wi-Fi CC3200 LaunchPad CC3200-LAUNCHXL (ACTIVE), which is fully active and recommended by GCP IoT Site page. Do you have any recommendation board which I can purchase?

Comment: ESP32 is altogther differnt beast. TI Sensortag is much efficient, robust and non-bulky thing. 
Any inputs on CC3200 device, will help

Comment: Currently, this hardware device is not connected to the computer. (Code 45)

To fix this problem, reconnect this hardware device to the computer.

Comment: I was able to connect after jumper setting changed to J8 to SOP as per documentation provided by TI


On command prompt when trying to run below
D:\app1>d:\mos flash cc3200
Fetching https://github.com/mongoose-os-apps/demo-c/releases/download/latest/demo-c-cc3200.zip...
  done, 376115 bytes.
Loaded demo-c/cc3200 version 1.0 (20190618-213947/2.12.0-g7949302-master)
Using port COM7

Comment: Probably worth updating with an update for your question, glad you got it working!